# Blender - Weird rotation when exporting to fbx

Tags: export, .fbx

I have an issue when i export an animation as Fbx. It happens when i rotate my character in the Z global axis of the bone or in the Y local axis of the bone.
(Ignore the mesh deformation, is a test)

This is what I expected
[image: This is what I expected]

And this is what i got
[image: And this is what i got]

I reimported to blender to see the result quickly. But i want to use it in Unreal and the result is the same

This situation happened before and i fixed joining all the mesh in one, but now i already have one mesh.

Hope you can help me. Thank you

Comment: Thanks. Hm, that looks really strange. (PS: I refound this question later)

Comment: Wish I could help :(